# SVG: Append Title to selfclosing Path concludes with invalid XML in IE11

Tags: javascript, svg, internet-explorer-11

I encountered a new problem since the latest update of IE11 (11.309.16299.0), which I am able to demonstrate with the following snippet:

```
var tE = document.createElement("div");
tE.innerHTML = "<svg><g><path /><path></path></g></svg>";

var tT = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'title');
tT.textContent = 'test';

tE.querySelector('path').appendChild(tT);

console.log(new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(tE.firstChild));
```

### IE11 (11.309.16299.0):

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><g><path><title>test</title></path></path><path /></g></svg>
```

*This one returns invalid XML, which is not okay*

### IE11 (before 11.309.16299.0), Chrome, Firefox and Edge:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><g><path><title>test</title></path><path/></g></svg>
```

*This one returns what I am looking for*

How am I to handle that new case with invalid XML provided by the new version of IE11?

### Edit:

Apparently the version of IE11 does not really matter, it just was not noticed anytime sooner.

Comment: You should report bugs in Microsoft products to Microsoft's bug tracking systems.

Comment: @Robert Longson: Alright, I did send a report. I am going to post the response once I receive it.

Comment: The support for IE11 kind of ran out and I really doubt it will still be addressed. If some moderator wants to close this one. Feel free to.